# Hash Validation

Tags: php, sql, hash, salt

Hello This is my current code I'm working on:

```
$uname = "unholybanana";
$pass = "choykiller13";
$salt = salty();
$password = sha1 ( $uname . $pass . $salt );
echo $password;

function salty() {
    mt_srand(microtime(true)*100000 + memory_get_usage(true));
    return md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
}
```

So far my problem is $password echos $uname+$pass hashed mixed but it doesn't mix with salt anyone can point out a problem with this. I'm currently just using sha1 for learning purposes rather than go straight to scrypt and bcrypt. Also this is what would i do to insert the data into the db:

```
    $sql= "INERT into test SET uname='$uname', hashpass='$password', salt='$salt'";
```

Would be great if anyone can spot if there is a problem with my insert above.

So far i have no idea how am i able to validate this.(syntax) would appreciate anyone would point me in a good direction.

But i think it should be still thinking how i would go about coding this.

```
     $checkpass= sha1 ( $uname . $pass . $salt ) == $hashpass;
```

Also i wanted to add $uname because all of my unames are given to the client so all unames would look like this C-9183102.

Would appreciate any help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost definitely want

```
$sql= "INSERT into test SET uname='$uname', hashpass='$password', salt='$salt'";
```

instead of `INERT`.

Comment: Hahaha didn't see that typo. =D